# How to capture a part of webpage using jquery

Tags: jquery, screenshot

I want to capture a part of webpage using jQuery but instead, it captures the whole page.

Something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="top"><p>Hello World!</p></div>
        <div id="middle"><p>World Hello!</p></div>
        <div id="bottom"><p>Hello World!</p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to capture only the `<div id="bottom"></div>` part.
Please tell me how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Which part? Also, please include the `jQuery` codes you have written so far.

Comment: What is the meaning of  `Capture`?

Comment: use display:none; for another two selector.., is this you want?

Comment: capture means html elements to capture and put it in some other place?

Comment: I'm expecting a javascript function to be used to capture or screenshot.

Comment: for get screen shot you can use phantomjs

Comment: but how could I filter the elements without using css